# How do I create a function that will run input-dependent sums or outcomes in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, permutation, google-sheets-formula

I have built a spreadsheet for a game I play.  Its purpose is to demonstrate the amount of points earned after each round.  The amount of points earned is dependent on the win/loss of that round, and then the points compound or retract accordingly.

There are 24 matches that are played in this game, with a possible result of win/loss for each round.  So, there are 48 different individual results that can occur.  The complicated thing is that each round's points depends on win/loss, as well as the previous round's individual earnings.  For example, if Round 2 is won and earns 120 points, and Round 3 is won, it earns 150 points.  But if Round 3 is lost, 120 points is earned.

I am looking to build a program or function that will compute the final score of every one of the 16,777216 possible combination of outcomes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the final score consist of adding up scores from each round, or is scoring accumulative so that the final match score is also the final total score?  Also, does "every one of the ... possible combinations" assume a particular win/loss sequence is a given?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow.